# creating nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have looked at many examples but cant seem to get to make an nested array to store some data nicely. How can I get the following code to work? It gives me an error now:

```
var shipdata = [];

shipdata['header']['bedrijfsnaam'] = $('[name="bedrijfsnaam"]').val();
shipdata['header']['naam'] = $('[name="naam"]').val();
shipdata['header']['straat'] = $('[name="straat"]').val();
shipdata['header']['postcode'] = $('[name="postcode"]').val();
shipdata['header']['plaats'] = $('[name="plaats"]').val();
shipdata['header']['telefoon'] = $('[name="telefoon"]').val();
shipdata['header']['email'] = $('[name="email"]').val();
shipdata['header']['instructies'] = $('[name="instructies"]').val();
shipdata['header']['ordernummertje'] = $('[name="ordernummertje"]').val();

$(".pakketten").each(function(index, element) {

            index++;
            shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index]['lengte'] = $('[name="lengte'+index+'"]').val(),
            shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index]['breedte'] = $('[name="breedte'+index+'"]').val(),
            shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index]['hoogte'] = $('[name="hoogte'+index+'"]').val(),
            shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index]['gewicht'] $('[name="gewicht'+index+'"]').val()


        });
```

Probably im doing this all wrong, but some pointers would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you actually want an object, arrays are referenced via index, objects have actual key/val pairs.

Comment: It's an object, not an array. Javascript doesn't have arrays with string keys.

Comment: index++ is not necessary

Comment: You should first initialize 1st level arrays, like `shipdata['header'] = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are creating an object and not an array, so use `{}` instead of `[]` for the main container.

Second, when inserting multiple values at the same time, you can use a much more compact notation:

```
var shipdata = {
  'header': {
    'bedrijfsnaam': $('[name="bedrijfsnaam"]').val(),
    'naam': $('[name="naam"]').val()
    '...': '...'
  },
  'pakketten': []
};

$(".pakketten").each(function(index, element) {
            shipdata['pakketten'].push({
              'lengte': $('[name="lengte'+index+'"]').val(),
              'breedte': $('[name="breedte'+index+'"]').val(),
              '...': '...'
            });
});
```

Besides, anytime you want to access an object or array in any way, you have to initialize it beforehand as already mentioned by @antyrat.

Comment: thanks this seems to work, but can I create a JSON object out of this? Because now the top part is an object, and the pakketten part is an array.

Comment: @Snuur If you want to create a JSON-string out of it, it does not matter, whether the content is an array or an object. In both cases you can use `JSON.stringify( shipdata )` to get the JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create objects each time you want to have nested array:

```
var shipdata = {};
shipdata['header'] = {};
shipdata['header']['bedrijfsnaam'] = $('[name="bedrijfsnaam"]').val();
//...

shipdata['pakketten'] = {};

$(".pakketten").each(function(index, element) {

    index++;
    shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index] = {};
    shipdata['pakketten']['pakket'+index]['lengte'] = $('[name="lengte'+index+'"]').val(),
    // ...
```

Answer updated due to comments as arrays didn't have string indexes.